# How to edit an html file using variables from a json file and jquery? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have the following json file

```
{
    "subject":"CSE",
    "semester":"Fall",
    "number":"219",
    "year":"2017",
    "title":"Title",
    "instructor_name":"Instructor Name",
    "instructor_home":"Instructor Home",
    "export_dir":"",
    "template_dir":"",
    "home_page_boolean":true,
    "syllabus_page_boolean":true,
    "schedule_page_boolean":true,
    "hws_page_boolean":true,
    "project_page_boolean":true,
    "banner_school_image_file":"test.jpeg",
    "left_footer_image_file":"test.jpeg",
    "right_footer_image_file":"test.jpeg"
}
```

I also have the following html file

```
/*109923473*/

<html>
    <head>
        <title>CSE 380 Home Page - Spring 2017</title> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/course_homepage_layout.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/sea_wolf.css">

    <!-- LINK TO OUR JQuery -->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="content">

            <div id="navbar">
                <a href="http://www.stonybrook.edu/"><img class="sbu_navbar" alt="Name" src="./images/ImageLogo.png"></a>

                <a id="home_link" class="open_nav" href="index.html">Home</a>
                <a id="syllabus_link" class="nav" href="syllabus.html">Syllabus</a>
                <a id="schedule_link" class="nav" href="schedule.html">Schedule</a>
                <a id="hws_link" class="nav" href="hws.html">HWs</a>
                <a id="projects_link" class="nav" href="projects.html">Projects</a>
            </div>

            <div id="banner">
                CSE 380 - Spring 2017<br>
                Computer Game Programming
            </div>

            <div id="desc">

                <h4> ANNOUNCEMENTS:</h4>

                <p>Welcome to the CSE 380 Web site. </p>
                <br><br><br><br><br>
                <hr>
```

The json data is not in the html file. It's a separate text file called CourseDetails.json

I need to change three things.

1. Replace the various course details. So for example, in the html in the title and announcement the CSE 380 Spring 2017 part is hardcoded. I want to replace all of those details with that which is in my json file.

Is there any way to set up variables in the html file, set them to the values in the json file and then just use variable instead of hardcoded data?

2. I also have 5 boolean json data variables. Those are supposed to control which of the site pages in the navbar show up. For example, if the json file contained

   "syllabus_page_boolean":false
   "schedule_page_boolean":false

Then the navbar portion of the html file should only be

```
<div id="navbar">
    <a href="http://www.stonybrook.edu/"><img class="sbu_navbar" alt="Name" src="./images/ImageLogo.png"></a>

    <a id="home_link" class="open_nav" href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a id="hws_link" class="nav" href="hws.html">HWs</a>
    <a id="projects_link" class="nav" href="projects.html">Projects</a>
</div>
```

3. This is very similar to part one but in the html file I have a path file for an image

   ```
    <a href="http://www.stonybrook.edu/"><img class="sbu_navbar" alt="Name" src="./images/ImageLogo.png"></a>
   ```

How would I replace the hardcoded path file with the path file from my json file (left_footer_image)

Thanks!

Comment: What you're attempting to do is not at all trivial. Additionally, javascript is not the best way to do this. If you are required to use JS, you're going to need to write a fairly involved javascript and include it on every one of your HTML pages (you're going to need to edit them). Can you provide further information on your situation? There's a reasonable solution for this, but I don't think it's JS.

Comment: I'm not required to use javascript I just assumed that would be the best way. What other information do you think will be helpful?

Comment: If this were me, I would use python (or maybe even PHP, but python is nicer to work with). What you'll want to do is create a template from your HTML file that replaces the variables with a placeholder, like this: <title>{{ course_name }}</title> ... Once you have the template created you can manually search and replace the place holders with the actual values to create the HTML file. Python has some nice templating engines (Jinja2, Mako) that will do this for you.